# How to change locale i18n in Grails after login (with acegi)?

Tags: grails, internationalization

I want to change the Locale depending of the user perferences. 
I used onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent :

```
onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = {e, appCtx ->
   def autservice = appCtx.authenticateService
        def user = autservice.userDomain()            
        if (user) {
            def request = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityRequestHolder.getRequest()
            def person = lli.faqapp.security.User.get(user.id)                
            ... But ????
        }
}
```

I would like to redirect or set Locale but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This technique worked worked for me:
http://archive.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.grails.user/msg/82adcb901001260643q3fe98f4cq260afff3446d379f@mail.gmail.com

Note that every controller needs to extend AuthBase.

Comment: but which is the package of AuthBaseController ? Thanks

Comment: import org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.controller.AuthBase